# IntelliJ debugger does not stop after adding JFileChooser to my project

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

#### Synopsis

I am developing a Java Swing project, and I have been debugging successfully within IntelliJ IDEA by running the main method directly. After closing the frame, the debugger exits normally.

However, after adding a `JFileChooser` dialog to the project, the debugger does not exit normally. I have to click the stop button every time now, which causes the JVM to exit with a non-zero status.

#### Minimal, Reproducible Example

This is the section of code that is causing the problem; it is an `ActionListener` that I am adding to two buttons which launch the `JFileChooser`:

```
/**
 * Generic action listener that is used for both file selection dialog buttons
 */
private final ActionListener fileSelectionButtonActionListener = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event)
    {
        final String target = ((JButton) event.getSource()).getName();
        assert (target.equals("file") || target.equals("directory"));

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());
        fileChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
        if(target.equals("directory")) {
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        }
        final int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            if(target.equals("file")) {
                fileTextField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                directoryTextField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### Debugging Steps

I have tried moving the `JFrame` creation from the parameter of the `showOpenDialog` method to a variable declaration and added `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` but that did not fix the issue. It's almost like the frame is still hanging around in memory, and that's why the JVM won't close.

#### Question

How can I make the JVM close appropriately while using `JFileChooser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, indeed, that the `JFrame` is still in memory, causing the JVM to hang. However, **the solution is a `JFrame` is not needed.**

Instead of setting a `new JFrame()` as the parent of the dialog, set the parent to the dialog window itself:

```
/**
 * Generic action listener that is used for both file selection dialog buttons
 */
private final ActionListener fileSelectionButtonActionListener = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event)
    {
        final String target = ((JButton) event.getSource()).getName();
        assert (target.equals("file") || target.equals("directory"));

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());
        fileChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
        if(target.equals("directory")) {
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        }
-->     final int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);     <--
        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            if(target.equals("file")) {
                fileTextField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                directoryTextField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Change the line where you get the result: `final int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);`. Doing that fixes the issue.

Comment: Never heard of a JFrame hanging in memory causes the JVM not to exit. Do you mean the UI thread?